# Firemonkey 3dlayer access

Tags: firemonkey

I would like your help on an application I am making in Embarcadero Firemonkey.

I am using a FMX form , on top I have a viewport3D , align as CLIENT and on top of the viewpoer3d I have put two (2) layer3D positioned the one covering the other, layer3d1 covering the layer3d2.

On both layer3d I have several buttons. So my problem is that I can access the layer3d2 buttons even when it is covered by layer3d1.

The hittest on both layer3d are TRUE.They are not transparent, loaded with an image from a bitmap.

Does anyone know how solve this?

Regards
Ioannis

Comment: Sorry , something else also. Both layer3d have a float animation which makes them spin around the X axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found why this is not happening. All the 2D objects has priority to stay in front of the 3D . So This is why it is happenning

The solution for e here is to use a 3D object instead of using a TImage which is a 2D object.

Regards
Ioannis